# Howcome the string "b" is accepted by this nondeterministic finite state automata per the given solution?

Tags: automata

[image: NFSA and solution to the language set it accepts]

Am I correct that the given solution is implying that the string with a single b, "b" is accepted by this NFSA? If so, I don't understand how "b" can end up in the accepting state.

Comment: The solution is wrong. The NFA accepts $abbb$.

Comment: Your NFA accepts all words except those starting with an odd run of $b$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks, I also go to uoft and this example was cited in one of the lecture notes.

Comment: @Shukie Please add an accessible url or reference to that "one of the lecture notes".